# Access a button's @IBInspectable variable from it's @IBAction

Tags: swift

I am creating button views in the storyboard that open an URL, where the URL can be set in the Inspector as an @IBInspectable per button.

My issue is that I can only connect the button's action to an @IBAction in the ViewController, from which the custom class CustomButton's variables or functions seem to be inaccessible.

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBAction func openURL(sender: CustomButton) {
    let theURL = self.myURL; // accesses parent ViewController, not CustomButton, where the variable is defined for this view
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: theURL)!)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

**Button.swift**

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {
    @IBInspectable var myURL: String?
    @IBInspectable var myPhone: String?
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself what `self` means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
let theURL = self.myURL
```

to

```
let theURL = sender.myURL
```